# writing an R function with if statement that relies on multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to write an R function that consists of an if statement where when a condition in column A is true, it does a calculation to a value in column B, otherwise it just returns the value from column B. I'm sure this is easy to do and I'm just missing something basic, but I am struggling. Is there a good way to do this?

Here's an example of what I tried

```
example_df <- data.frame(
  type = c("oranges", "apples", "oranges", "oranges", "apples"),
  sold = c(6, 7, 1, 4, 1)
)

multiply_oranges <- function(x) { if (x$type == "oranges") {
    x$sold * 10
  } else {
    x$sold
  }
}
lapply(example_df, multiply_oranges)
```

But that gives me

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

and I'm having trouble understanding what that means/how to fix it.

Any help in either fixing this function or showing me a better way to do this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unless your frame is a single row, you should use `ifelse` to do a vectorized if/else. In case I'm wrong, you need to replace *"but doesn't work"* with **how** it didn't work, including errors/warnings and/or incorrect output.

Comment: (I'd think replacing the body of your function with `x$sold <- x$sold * ifelse(x$type == "oranges", 10, 1)` might work. Of course, it's missing some safeguards. For example, verify `stopifnot(all(c("sold","type") %in% names(x)))`.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks! I updated the question with what isn't working (Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors). Your solution does work, but the real problem I'm working with is a little more complex and I think I need to do the calculation within the function, and having trouble doing that with ifelse

i.e. if I do multiply_oranges2 <- function(x) { ifelse(x$type == "oranges", x$sold * 10, x$sold) }

and then lapply(example_df, multiply_oranges)

I still get Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: What do you _expect_ `lapply(example_df, multiply_oranges)` to return?

Comment: ideally a vector of 60, 7, 10, 40, 1. But maybe I'm using lapply wrong?

Comment: `lapply(example_df, ...)` is going to call the function once for each column. The first time you call it, the `x` that it sees is really `example_df$type`, which is a vector. As a quick example `(1:3)$foo` is going to err in the same way, because it makes no sense. You don't need `lapply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is what you're after:

```
library(dplyr)
example_df %>% 
  mutate(Cost=ifelse(type=="oranges", sold*10, sold))
    type sold Cost
1 oranges    6   60
2  apples    7    7
3 oranges    1   10
4 oranges    4   40
5  apples    1    1
```

But that seems like a lot of effort, especially if you want to add more fruit. You should have another data frame containing the prices for each fruit.

```
Prices <- data.frame(price=c(10,5), type=c("oranges","apples"))
Prices
  price    type
1    10 oranges
2     5  apples
```

Then join them together and calculate the net price:

```
library(tidyr)
example_df %>% 
  inner_join(Prices) %>%
  mutate(Net=sold*price)
Joining, by = "type"
     type sold price Net
1 oranges    6    10  60
2  apples    7     5  35
3 oranges    1    10  10
4 oranges    4    10  40
5  apples    1     5   5
```

Comment: Thank you, the first example with the ifelse inside the mutate is I think exactly what I've been looking for. 

For the second part, thank you that's helpful to know. I think I may have phrased my question badly -- the real work I'm doing is actually applying a curl function for some observations and not others. But that seemed complicated to explain so I tried to make up some simple example data that would get at the same problem I was having.

Answer (score 2):

1. `lapply` is not necessary; that would be useful it you have a list of frames (even just one). You don't. The argument that your function is being given is one column at a time. It "unrolls" as:

   ```r
   multiply_oranges(example_df$type)
   multiply_oranges(example_df$sold)
   ```

   Which is not what (I think) you intend.
2. Your `if` is wrong. R's `if` **requires** that its condition be length 1; if it is more, it will warn you with:

   ```
   Warning in if (x$type == "oranges") { :
     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
   ```

   which is effectively telling you that the value of the first value in `$type` is being used for *all* in the vector, which is also (I believe) not what you intend. Instead, use `ifelse`.

Try this:

```r
multiply_oranges <- function(x) x$sold * ifelse(x$type == "oranges", 10, 1)
multiply_oranges(example_df)
# [1] 60  7 10 40  1
```

The function `ifelse` is doing the condition for each element in the vector. If you look at the `ifelse` by itself, you'll see

```
x$type == "oranges"
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
ifelse(x$type == "oranges", 10, 1)
# [1] 10  1 10 10  1
x$sold * ifelse(x$type == "oranges", 10, 1)
# [1] 60  7 10 40  1
```